# multiple AND conditions for a single column in where clause

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with column `ID`, datatype `Integer`, now my requirement is to select data from table that matches certain values like

```
ID
1
2
3
4
```

Possible conditons:

if ID = 1 and ID = 2 then retrive the dataset, if ID = 1 and ID = 5 then don't return result set.

now here is the whole issue:

I am not sure how to write this condition with `And` clause

If I write

```
select ID where ID = 1 and ID =2
```

this doesn't return any rows.

Not sure how to write query for this particular condition, Also I can't use `OR` because my requirement is table should contain both the values then return the result set.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to return whole dataset when all conditions are met, nothing otherwise. If so you can count distinct matching id:

```
select * 
  from t 
  where (select count(distinct id) from t where id in (1, 2)) = 2;
```

or use `exists` twice / multiple times:

```
select id 
  from t
  where exists (select null from t where id = 1)
    and exists (select null from t where id = 2);
```

If you want only matching rows, when both values exists in table add `and id in (1, 2)` condition to `where` clause.

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c7b26c084ef1b79ae9d17210ac8e4699)</sup>**

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, looks like it works but requirement is dynamic, for e.g I have given only 2 values but in actual case their can be N values, what is way out in that case?

Comment: Everything you have to do is to check if number of distinct values equals N in first query. Or in second query put additional `exists`.

Answer (score 0):

A column cannot have two values in the same row, so you will never have ID=1 AND ID=2 in the same row. This is why you're not seeing any data returned. Your condition will *always* be false.

You need to say something like this:

```
select id where id=1 OR id=2;
```

or like this:

```
select id where id in (1,2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, already tried but didn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use IN clause if you need to filter multiple values from same column. AND should be used to apply filter in different columns. Do not provide 5 in your condition, by default it will be omitted

```
select ID from table where ID in (1, 2);
```

You can also use between operator,

```
select ID from table where ID between 1 and 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, didn't get the expected result

Answer (score 0):

im probably late for this but perhaps you're not getting anything back bc you didnt specify which table you were pulling data from?

Comment: I am trying to get the two values from two rows that corresponds to `AND` condition in general terms

Answer (score 0):

Please tell me if this answers your question:

```
Select * yourtable where EXISTS(
select * from yourtable
where id = 1
UNION
select * from yourtable
where id = 2)
AND NOT EXISTS(select * from yourtable
where id = 1 OR id = 5);
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, I can't use two values inside a `id` column